# Где собирать объекты с высоким уровнем вложенности?

Tags: php, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Теоретическая задача.

Моделирую ситуацию: нужно получить статьи, у которых есть комментарии, которые в свою очередь имеют авторов, которые в свою очередь имеют тоже какую-нить коллекцию. Все это надо вывести одновременно на одной странице. В общем получается коллекция статей и 4 уровня объектов в ней.

Вопрос: как логичнее получить эту коллекцию из репозитория? Два варианта:

1) Одним методом: репозиторий отдает сервису сразу коллекцию статей со всеми уровнями вложенности.

2) 2 или более обращений к репозиториям: одним методом получаем статьи с комментариями, вторым методом пользователей с их коллекцией относительно комментариев из первого метода. Коллекцию в один пул собираем уже на уровне выше - в сервисе/интеракторе.

Плюсы первого вариант - вроде логично, сервис делает запрос на получение объектов, получает их.

Второй вариант - чисто теоретически, если вложенность будет 10 уровня, то сервис будет собирать объекты из мелких методов разных репозиториев, причем можно будет собирать как лего, вместо одного огромного метода в репозитории.

Comment: Это на ваше усмотрение и требование ТЗ. В конце концов есть [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/) и его аналоги, где можно запрашивать и получать необходимые уровни вложенности и данные для каждого уровня.

Comment: Если рассматривать репозиторий как интерфейс для получения данных, то я бы не стал в нем делать логику для сбора разношерстных данных, преобразование их для вывода и еще что-нибудь. Только если это и вправду не делается одним запросом. Но даже в случае с одним запросом вряд ли на выходе из БД оно будет в нужном формате =). Лучше разделять ответственность: Доступ к данным, формирование ответа и тд.